# How to type a text with Android Keyboard with Appium and Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

**Introduction**

I am developing a script in Python 3.7 using Appium. It will automate some task on a Real Android  smartphone. My script need to type some text in textfield.
I don't want to use send_keys method or ActionChains.
I would prefer to type the text, character by character, using the keyboard of the smartphone.

**Problem**

I investigate and read various docs:

press-keycode

https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/commands/device/keys/press-keycode/

which brings me to Keyevent

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Which brings me to KeyCharacterMap

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyCharacterMap.html

To be honest with you, after I read it all, it is super difficult for me to undestand all that.

So I made some experimentations by trying different lines of code to see what happens:

```
driver.press_keycode(0)
driver.press_keycode(1)
driver.press_keycode(2)
```

etc...

It seems than nothing happen.

Is there anyone who knows a good tutorial or article which can explain me how to type a text in a textfield of an Android smartphone Application using the keyboard instead of send_keys method and ActionChains?

Could you help me please to find the way?

Comment: I need to check in python but in java we can type with device keyboard.

Comment: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/10900 here you can read that Appium support (for all language bindings) for typing from device keyboard is removed probably because it was slow. Now press keycode is a workaround. Else you can invoke **adb input** command for typing from keyboard. May i know what is exact scenario or use case?

Comment: @Muzzamil thanks. Obviously, it has been removed from new version. This is sad.

Comment: May I know use case?

Comment: @Muzzamil My script need to type a text. I want to simulate human behaviour. So I tried to use a actionchains, but the move_to_element create issue as the cursor doesn’t go immediately after the character typed. So I used xoffset, but when a new line is created, the script carry on to type on first line. This how I get the idea to simply tap the letters of keyboard. By this way, i will not have to fix the xoffset and yoffset.